# Updating Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am super new to Apex and am trying to update some code in production. I have it working in a sandbox but the problem is getting enough test coverage. I didn't write this so I am trying to work with the existing test class. The problem is that the test class creates the records for testing then creates a map of the old records to compare to the new created. So they end up being equal and the code doesn't run. This doesn't occur when entering the data in directly so it's specifically a test class issue.

In the Test Class, if I take out the bolded code, it works fine. So I'm trying to find out how I can make the old record not equal to the new record in the test class so it will pass this If statement.

```java
//For new PE records
for(Program_Enrollment__c programRec : newRecords){      
    Program_Enrollment__c old = oldMap.get(programRec.id);
                    
    //Check old end date value and new values is not same and end date not null 
    if(**programRec.End_Date__c != old.End_Date__c &&** programRec.End_Date__c != Null && 
        programRec.end_date__c >= programRec.start_date__c && 
        (programRec.RecordTypeID.equals(SHSRecordTypeID) || programRec.RecordTypeID
```

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Here is the Trigger Handler code:

```java
public without sharing class  ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler{
    public void beforeInsert(List<Program_Enrollment__c> newRecords){
        // not material to the question
    }
    
    public void beforeUpdate(List<Program_Enrollment__c> newRecords, Map<Id,Program_Enrollment__c> oldMap){
        // Get a list of all Parent Ids
        Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
        //Get Record type where name = Saura       
        Id recordTypeIdSaura = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId();
        for(Program_Enrollment__c programRec : newRecords){ 
            parentIds.add(programRec.Contact__c);
            //oldMap.put(programRec.id, programRec);
            Program_Enrollment__c old = oldMap.get(programRec.id);        
            // Check if new value and old value is differnt 
            if(programRec.RecordTypeId == recordTypeIdSaura) {
                if(programRec.Next_Court_Date__c != null){
                    if((programRec.Status__c != old.Status__c) || (programRec.Next_Court_Date__c != old.Next_Court_Date__c)){
                        Date addedValues = Date.Today().addDays(7);
                        if(addedValues >= programRec.Next_Court_Date__c ){
                            programRec.Court_Date_w_in_7_Days__c = True;
                        }  
                    }   
                } 
            }
        }
        // Get a map of all Parents with field information
        Map<Id, Contact> parentsById = new Map<Id, Contact>();
        parentsById.putAll([SELECT Id, Age__c , birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :parentIds and Age__c != Null and birthdate != Null]);
        
        //For new PE records
        for(Program_Enrollment__c programRec : newRecords)
        {
            if( parentsById.containsKey(programRec.contact__c) && programRec.Start_date__c != Null ){
                Integer NumberOfMonths = parentsById.get(programRec.Contact__c).birthdate.monthsBetween(programRec.Start_date__c);
                programRec.Age_at_Enrollment__c=  NumberOfMonths/12;
            } 
        }
        //Create Adult Assessment Housing Follow-Up future records 
        Id housingFollowUpRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Adult_Assessment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Housing_Follow_Up').getRecordTypeId();
                
        List<Adult_Assessment__c> AdultAssessmentList = new List<Adult_Assessment__c>();      
        
        //Get Names of record types
        Id HousingRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Housing').getRecordTypeId();
        Id SHSRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('SHS').getRecordTypeId();   

        /**
        ********************************************** 
        Editor's note: This is the problematic section
        **********************************************
        */
        //For new PE records
        for(Program_Enrollment__c programRec : newRecords){      
            Program_Enrollment__c old = oldMap.get(programRec.id);
          
            system.debug('Program Rec ID: '+ programRec.id);
            system.debug('Old End Date after map ' + old.End_Date__c);
            //Check old end date value and new values is not same and end date not null 
            if(programRec.End_Date__c != old.End_Date__c && programRec.End_Date__c != Null && programRec.end_date__c >= programRec.start_date__c && (programRec.RecordTypeID.equals(SHSRecordTypeID) || programRec.RecordTypeID.equals(HousingRecordTypeID))){
                system.debug('End Date  ' + programRec.End_Date__c + 'Old End Date  ' +  old.End_Date__c + '   Start Date   ' + programRec.start_date__c + ' Prog Rec Type ' + programRec.RecordTypeID );
                Adult_Assessment__c AdultAssRecord1 = new Adult_Assessment__c();
                AdultAssRecord1.RecordTypeId = housingFollowUpRecordTypeId;
                AdultAssRecord1.FollowUp_Result__c = 'Scheduled';
                AdultAssRecord1.ProgramEnrollment__c = programRec.Id;
                AdultAssRecord1.Contact__c = programRec.Contact__c;
                AdultAssRecord1.Assessment_Date__c = programRec.End_Date__c + 90;
                AdultAssRecord1.Type_Of_Assessment__c = '3-Month';
                AdultAssRecord1.Program__c = programRec.Program__c;
                AdultAssessmentList.add(AdultAssRecord1);
                Adult_Assessment__c AdultAssRecord2 = new Adult_Assessment__c();
                AdultAssRecord2.RecordTypeId = housingFollowUpRecordTypeId;
                AdultAssRecord2.FollowUp_Result__c = 'Scheduled';
                AdultAssRecord2.ProgramEnrollment__c = programRec.Id;
                AdultAssRecord2.Contact__c = programRec.Contact__c;
                AdultAssRecord2.Assessment_Date__c = programRec.End_Date__c + 180;
                AdultAssRecord2.Type_Of_Assessment__c = '6-Month';
                AdultAssRecord2.Program__c = programRec.Program__c;
                AdultAssessmentList.add(AdultAssRecord2);
                Adult_Assessment__c AdultAssRecord3 = new Adult_Assessment__c();
                AdultAssRecord3.RecordTypeId  = housingFollowUpRecordTypeId;
                AdultAssRecord3.FollowUp_Result__c = 'Scheduled';
                AdultAssRecord3.ProgramEnrollment__c = programRec.Id;
                AdultAssRecord3.Contact__c = programRec.Contact__c;
                AdultAssRecord3.Assessment_Date__c = programRec.End_Date__c + 274;
                AdultAssRecord3.Type_Of_Assessment__c = '9-Month';
                AdultAssRecord3.Program__c = programRec.Program__c;
                AdultAssessmentList.add(AdultAssRecord3);
                Adult_Assessment__c AdultAssRecord4 = new Adult_Assessment__c();            
                AdultAssRecord4.RecordTypeId = housingFollowUpRecordTypeId;
                AdultAssRecord4.FollowUp_Result__c = 'Scheduled';
                AdultAssRecord4.ProgramEnrollment__c = programRec.Id;
                AdultAssRecord4.Contact__c = programRec.Contact__c;
                AdultAssRecord4.Assessment_Date__c = programRec.End_Date__c + 365; 
                AdultAssRecord4.Type_Of_Assessment__c = '12-Month';
                AdultAssRecord4.Program__c = programRec.Program__c;
                AdultAssessmentList.add(AdultAssRecord4);
            }       
        }
        //Then insert Adult Assessment record
        Database.Insert(AdultAssessmentList);
    }
    public void afterInsert(List<Program_Enrollment__c> triggerNew){
        handleSharing(triggerNew, null);    
    }
    public void afterUpdate(List<Program_Enrollment__c> triggerNew, Map<Id, Program_Enrollment__c> oldMap){
        handleSharing(triggerNew, oldMap);
    }
    private void handleSharing(List<Program_Enrollment__c> triggerNew, Map<Id, Program_Enrollment__c> oldMap) {
        // Not material to the question
    }

    public  void calculateCaseloadInsertDelete(List<Program_Enrollment__c> allEnrollments) {

        Set<Id> providerList = new Set<Id>();
        for (Program_Enrollment__c enrollment : allEnrollments) {
            if (enrollment.Status__c == 'Participating' && enrollment.Provider__c != null) {
                providerList.add(enrollment.Provider__c);
            }
        }
        if (!providerList.isEmpty()) {
            updateAccounts(providerList);
        }       
    }

public void recalculateCaseloadUpdate(List<Program_Enrollment__c> triggerNew, Map<Id, Program_Enrollment__c> triggerOldMap) {

        Set<Id> providerList = new Set<Id>();
        for (Program_Enrollment__c enrollment : triggerNew) {
            if (enrollment.Status__c == 'Participating' && enrollment.Provider__c != null) {
                providerList.add(enrollment.Provider__c);
            }
            if (triggerOldMap.get(enrollment.Id).Status__c == 'Participating' && enrollment.Status__c != 'Participating') {
                providerList.add(triggerOldMap.get(enrollment.Id).Provider__c);
            }
            if (triggerOldMap.get(enrollment.Id).Provider__c != enrollment.Provider__c && enrollment.Status__c == 'Participating') {
                providerList.add(triggerOldMap.get(enrollment.Id).Provider__c);
            }
        }        
        if (!providerList.isEmpty()) {
            updateAccounts(providerList);
        }       
    }

private void updateAccounts(Set<Id> providerList) {
        Map<String, Integer> enrollmentsCount = new Map<String, Integer>();
        
        List<AggregateResult> allEnrollments = [
            SELECT count(Id) recordCount, Provider__c, Status__c  
            FROM Program_Enrollment__c 
            WHERE Provider__c IN :providerList 
            GROUP BY Provider__c, Status__c];
        for (AggregateResult aggRes :allEnrollments) {
            enrollmentsCount.put('' + (String)aggRes.get('Provider__c') + (String)aggRes.get('Status__c'), (Integer) aggRes.get('recordCount'));
        }

        List<Account> accountsList = [SELECT Id, Current_Caseload__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :providerList];
        for (Account acc : accountsList) {
            if (enrollmentsCount.containsKey('' + acc.Id + 'Participating')) {
                acc.Current_Caseload__c = enrollmentsCount.get('' + acc.Id + 'Participating');
            } else {
                acc.Current_Caseload__c = 0;    
            }            
        }
        update accountsList;
    }
}
```

Here is the Test Class:

```java
@isTest
public class ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandlerTest {
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){     

        UserRole portalRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE PortalType = 'None' LIMIT 1];
        Profile profile1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
        User portalAccountOwner1 = new User(
            UserRoleId = portalRole.Id,
            ProfileId = profile1.Id,
            Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test2@test.com.hspr1',
            Alias = 'batman',
            Email='bruce.wayne@wayneenterprises.com.hspr',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            Firstname='Bruce',
            Lastname='Wayne',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
        );
        Database.insert(portalAccountOwner1);
    }

    @isTest
    private static void handleSharingTest_01() {
  
        //Create portal account owner
        User portalAccountOwner1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'bruce.wayne@wayneenterprises.com.hspr'];
        //Create account
        Account portalAccount1 = new Account(
            Name = 'TestAccount',
            OwnerId = portalAccountOwner1.Id,
            Current_Caseload__c = 1
        );
        Database.insert(portalAccount1);
            
        //Create contact
        Contact conObj = new Contact(
            FirstName = 'Test',
            Lastname = 'McTesty',
            AccountId = portalAccount1.Id,
            Email = System.now().millisecond() + 'test@test.com',
            RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Non-Client').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        Database.insert(conObj);

        Contact conObj2 = new Contact(
            FirstName = 'Test',
            Lastname = 'McTesty2',
            AccountId = portalAccount1.Id,
            Birthdate = Date.today().adddays(-3000),
            Email = System.now().millisecond() + 'test@test.com',
            RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Non-Client').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        Database.insert(conObj2);
            
        //Create users
        Profile portalProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'HSPR Partner Case Manager' Limit 1];
        User user1 = new User(
            Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test12345@test.com.hspr',
            ContactId = conObj.Id,
            ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
            Alias = 'test123',
            Email = 'test12345@test.com.hspr',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'McTesty',
            CommunityNickname = 'test12345',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        Database.insert(user1);

        portalProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'HSPR Partner Supervisor' Limit 1];
        User user2 = new User(
            Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test12345@test.com.hspr',
            ContactId = conObj2.Id,
            ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
            Alias = 'test123',
            Email = 'test12345@test.com.hspr',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'McTesty',
            CommunityNickname = 'test1234567',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        Database.insert(user2);

        Account accCW = new Account();
        accCW.Name = 'CW Test Organization';
        accCW.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Organization').getRecordTypeId();
        insert accCW;

        List<Account> conCWAccountId = [SELECT Id from Account where Name = 'CW Test Organization' LIMIT 1];
        Contact conCW = new Contact(
        AccountId = conCWAccountId[0].Id,
        LastName = 'CW Test LastName',
        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Non-Client').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert conCW;

        Account accAA = new Account();
        accAA.Name = 'AA Test Household';
        accAA.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household Account').getRecordTypeId();
        insert accAA;

        List<Account> conAAAccountId = [SELECT Id from Account where Name = 'AA Test Household' LIMIT 1];
        Contact conAA = new Contact();
        conAA.AccountId = conAAAccountId[0].Id;
        conAA.LastName = 'AA Test LastName';   
        conAA.npe01__PreferredPhone__c = 'Mobile';
        conAA.npe01__Preferred_Email__c = 'Personal';
        conAA.Phone = '3125551212';
        conAA.Email = 'AATest@Test.com';
        conAA.Birthdate = Date.today().adddays(-1800);
        conAA.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Client').getRecordTypeId();
        insert conAA;
        system.debug('LastName   '+ conaa.lastname + ' AccountID ' + conAAAccountId + '  Birthdate ' + conAA.birthdate) ;
               
        Program_Enrollment__c programobj = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        programobj.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId();
        programobj.Contact__c = conObj.id;
        programobj.Next_Court_Date__c = Date.today();
        programobj.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(-20);
        programobj.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(0);
        programobj.Status__c = 'Intake';  
        programobj.Provider__c = portalAccount1.Id;
        programobj.Provider_Case_Worker__c = conObj.Id; 
        programobj.Sponsor__c = conCW.Id;
        
        Program_Enrollment__c programobjHousing = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        programobjHousing.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Housing').getRecordTypeId();
        programobjHousing.Contact__c = conAA.id;
        programobjHousing.Name = 'X';
        programobjHousing.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(-50);
        programobjHousing.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(-30);
        programobjHousing.Program__c = 'Independent Supportive Housing';
        programobjHousing.Grant__c = 'a1qq00000014hLgAAI';
        system.debug('HousingID '+ programobjHousing.RecordTypeid + '  StartDate ' + programobjHousing.Start_date__c + '   EndDate  ' + programobjHousing.End_Date__c );
       
        Program_Enrollment__c programobjSHS = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        programobjSHS.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('SHS').getRecordTypeId();
        programobjSHS.Contact__c = conAA.id;
        programobjHousing.Name = 'X';
        programobjSHS.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(-10);
        programobjSHS.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(0);
        programobjHousing.Program__c = 'Supportive Housing Services';
        programobjHousing.Grant__c = 'a1qq00000014hLgAAI';
        
        Program_Enrollment__c programobjVRS = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        programobjVRS.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('VRS').getRecordTypeId();
        programobjVRS.Contact__c = conObj.id;
        programobjVRS.Next_Court_Date__c = Date.today();
        programobjVRS.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(-20);
        programobjVRS.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(0);
        programobjVRS.Status__c = 'Intake';  
        programobjVRS.Provider__c = portalAccount1.Id;
        programobjVRS.Provider_Case_Worker__c = conObj.Id; 
        programobjVRS.Sponsor__c = conCW.Id;
    
        Test.startTest();
            insert programobj;
            insert programobjHousing;
            insert programobjSHS;
            insert programobjVRS;
            ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler progEnrollCon = new ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler();
            List<Program_Enrollment__c> listPrograms = new List<Program_Enrollment__c>();
            listPrograms.add(programobjSHS);
            listPrograms.add(programobjHousing);
            listPrograms.add(programobjVRS);
            progEnrollCon.calculateCaseloadInsertDelete(listPrograms);
        Test.stopTest();    
    }

    @isTest 
    private static void calculateCaseLoadTest() { 
        Account acc = new Account( Name = 'TestAccount'); 
        insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact( LastName = 'CW Test LastName'); 
        insert con; 

        Account insertedAcc = [SELECT Id, Current_Caseload__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id]; 
        System.assertEquals(null, insertedAcc.Current_Caseload__c);

        Program_Enrollment__c pe1 = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        pe1.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId(); 
        pe1.Contact__c = con.id; 
        pe1.Next_Court_Date__c = Date.today(); 
        pe1.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(10); 
        pe1.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(30); 
        pe1.Status__c = 'Intake'; 
        pe1.Provider__c = acc.Id; 

        insert pe1;

        Program_Enrollment__c pe2 = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        pe2.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId(); 
        pe2.Contact__c = con.id; 
        pe2.Next_Court_Date__c = date.today().addDays(-7);
        pe2.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(10);
        pe2.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(30);
        pe2.Status__c = 'Intake'; 
        pe2.Provider__c = acc.Id; 
        insert pe2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Right now, there's not enough context surrounding the code you've shared for others to give much in the way of help. My best guess at the moment is that the same record instance is being put into both `oldMap` and `newRecords`. If so, that's easy enough to fix, but we'll need to see more of your code to give you more specific guidance. Seeing both the test code and the SUT (System Under Test, i.e. the code you're trying to cover with the test class) would help. Basically, we need to see how `newRecords` and `oldMap` are made, and then see how your test method is passing data.

Comment: I understand, but it is very long. I will try to provide the pertinent code.

Comment: Closer, but we're still missing information here. Your test class calls `calculateCaseloadInsertDelete()`, but that method isn't included in the trigger handler code that you've shared so far. The thing that is important here is to show us the `beforeUpdate()` method in the trigger handler, as well as everything that calls that `beforeUpdate()` method. In other words, we need to see the things involved in the chain of calls. Your test method(s) -> `ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler.calculateCaseloadInsertDelete()` -> [something else here] -> `ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate()`

Comment: @DerekF Thanks so much for review again. I apologize I didn't think I needed to add the code from the 2nd test method. I added the Handler code in the original post and I will add the 2nd test method in a response (ran out of room). Thanks!

Comment: 2nd Test Method:                                                                   @isTest 
    private static void calculateCaseLoadTest() {
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = 'TestAccount');
        insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact(
            LastName = 'CW Test LastName');
        insert con;                                                                                                     
 Account insertedAcc = [SELECT Id, Current_Caseload__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals(null, insertedAcc.Current_Caseload__c);

Comment: Program_Enrollment__c pe1 = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        pe1.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId();
        pe1.Contact__c = con.id;
        pe1.Next_Court_Date__c = Date.today();
        pe1.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(10);
        pe1.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(30);
        pe1.Status__c = 'Intake';  
        pe1.Provider__c = acc.Id;
        insert pe1;

Comment: Program_Enrollment__c pe2 = new Program_Enrollment__c();
        pe2.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Program_Enrollment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Saura').getRecordTypeId();
        pe2.Contact__c = con.id;
        pe2.Next_Court_Date__c = date.today().addDays(-7);
        pe2.Start_date__c = date.today().adddays(10);
        pe2.End_Date__c = date.today().adddays(30);
        pe2.Status__c = 'Intake';  
        pe2.Provider__c = acc.Id;
        insert pe2;
       }
}

Comment: I've removed some of the code that doesn't appear to be germane here, and added the other test method into your question. Unfortunately, I'm still not seeing anything that is calling `beforeUpdate()` here. Perhaps the issue lies in the trigger for `Program_Enrollment__c` itself. Can you add the trigger to your question? If the problem is indeed there, then it'd look something like `ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.newMap);`

Comment: Thanks @DerekF. I have attached Trigger code for the beforeUpdate()  in 3 comments.                            
trigger ProgramEnrollmentTrigger on Program_Enrollment__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete ) {
    ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler progEnrollCon = new ProgramEnrollmentTriggerHandler();
    AttendancetriggerHandler attHandlerobj= new AttendancetriggerHandler();
    String customSettingName = 'Disable_AttendanceTrigger__c';

Comment: if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        if (Trigger.isBefore) {
            // Process before insert
            progEnrollCon.beforeInsert(Trigger.new);
        } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            if (!birdseyeUtils.isDisableTrigger(customSettingName))  {  
                // Process after insert NR
                attHandlerobj.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
            }
            progEnrollCon.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
            progEnrollCon.calculateCaseloadInsertDelete(Trigger.new);
        }    }

Comment: else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if (Trigger.isBefore) {
            // Process before insert
            progEnrollCon.beforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            progEnrollCon.afterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
            progEnrollCon.recalculateCaseloadUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }

Comment: else if(Trigger.isDelete){
            if (!birdseyeUtils.isDisableTrigger(customSettingName))  {  
                 if (Trigger.isBefore) {
                     System.debug('Value in Trigger  old after if condition ' + trigger.old);
                     attHandlerobj.beforeDeleteEvent(Trigger.old);
                 } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
                     progEnrollCon.calculateCaseloadInsertDelete(Trigger.old);
                 }
            }
    }
}

Comment: @DerekF I think this is all the code, but let me know if you have any questions. I really appreciate your time on this.